# Where does Linux track who is a group admin through the gpasswd command?

Tags: linux, permissions, group, accounts

If I modify group membership and admins using the `gpasswd` command and add a user as a group admin Linux will allow that user to perform tasks otherwise reserved by root.

Ex.

```
[test1@centos ~]$ gpasswd -a test6 test
Adding user test6 to group test
```

If I try to perform the same task as a user that has not been added as an admin it is not allowed:

```
[test2@centos ~]$ gpasswd -a test7 test
gpasswd: Permission denied.
```

This has to be tracked somewhere. The `gpasswd` command has the SUID bit set but no indication as to who that is restricted to.

Where is this tracked? How does the `gpasswd` command know who has been granted elevated permissions?

Answer (score 2):

> Where is this tracked? How does the gpasswd command know who has been
>   granted elevated permissions?

It's not really "tracked", per se.  `gpasswd` has rules for which users have permission to use the command in various ways, and those rules/permissions are tested on every run of the command.  The results of those tests are not cached or stored.

In general, to run `gpasswd` you must either be root, or you must be defined as an administrative member of the group you are targeting, or you must be the *first* member of the group you are targeting.

---

If you'd like to get into specifics, we can examine the source of `gpasswd` and other parts of the [shadow-utils project](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow).

According to the [source for gpasswd](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/shadow/blob/debian/4.2-3/src/gpasswd.c) ([GitHub mirror](https://github.com/Distrotech/shadow-utils/blob/debian/4.2-3/src/gpasswd.c#L696)), depending on the results of `#ifdef SHADOWGRP` and `#ifdef FIRST_MEMBER_IS_ADMIN`, one of three checks is run in the `check_perms` function for a call to `gpasswd` that does not use the `-A` or `-M` flags (comments below are mine):

```
/* Check 1 */
if (!amroot && !is_on_list (sg->sg_adm, myname)) {
        failure ();
}

/* Check 2 */
if (!amroot) {
        if (gr->gr_mem[0] == (char *) 0) {
            failure ();
        }

        if (strcmp (gr->gr_mem[0], myname) != 0) {
            failure ();
        }
}

/* Check 3 */
if (!amroot) {
        failure ();
}
```

`amroot` is a boolean that is true if the root user has called `gpasswd`.  It is defined [here](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/shadow/blob/debian/4.2-3/src/gpasswd.c#L86):

```
/* The UID of the caller */
static uid_t bywho;
/* Indicate if gpasswd was called by root */
#define amroot  (0 == bywho)
```

Being root will "pass" (skip) Check 1, Check 2, and Check 3 (`amroot` will be `true`, which means `!amroot` will be `false`, so the if statement will be skipped).

A non-root user may pass Check 1 if they are an administrative member of the targeted group.  This is tested by passing a list of the targeted group's admin members (sg->sg_adm) and the username of the user who called `gpasswd` (myname) to the function `is_on_list`, defined [here](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/shadow/blob/debian/4.2-3/libmisc/list.c#L172).  If the calling user is in the group admin list, `is_on_list` returns `true`, which gets inverted to `false`, which allows the user to pass Check 1.

A non-root user may pass Check 2 if they are the *first listed member of the group they are trying to change*.  This is tested by verifying that the first user in the targeted group is equal to the user who called `gpasswd`.

A non-root user cannot pass Check 3.

---

Note:  All the source links that I provided are linked to the "debian/4.2-3" tag in the source repository.  This is to provide consistent references.